# Which line is the antiderivative and why?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, visualization

The graph of a function $f$ is shown. Which graph is an antiderivative of f and why?

[image]

This should be easy but I keep second guessing myself so I thought I'd check with you magnificent people. I'm thinking that none of them are and the antiderivative should look more like the black line here:

[image]

Am I on the right track with this?

Comment: Note that whenever $f$ is decreasing, $f' < 0$

Comment: Yeah, none of them seem to be correct. C,D can be ruled out. The derivatives of A and B seem to be increasing.

Comment: As a concrete example you can take the [derivative of the error function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=error+function+derivative) which is supposed to be an example of $f$ and the antiderivative [error function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+error+function) itself.

Comment: $f$ looks something like the $\arctan$ function. Maybe that information could be useful.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar It doesn't look like $\arctan$. Maybe $-\arctan$ after a translation, but definitely not $\arctan$.

Comment: @GitGud Right - so $f$ looks something like $a\arctan+c$.

Comment: It should be increasing and concave-down (someone please confirm), so none of the lines work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're correct (except insofar as the black line is not precise). $f$ is positive but decreasing: the derivatives of $C$ and $D$ are both negative, while the derivatives of $A$ and $B$ are both increasing, so none of them can be $f$.

Of the given lines, though, $B$ seems "least wrong".

Comment: Well, the OP's black line is definitely wrong (instead of being imprecise), or am I missing something?

Comment: Lord Soth: My drawing is sloppy. But it should be increasing more on the left than the right is all I meant to show.

Ben Millwood: thanks for the answer!